# python - remote hosts timezone vs local

Tags: python, hp-ux, pytz, zoneinfo

I'm building a web frontend for remote logs monitoring,
having to manage about 10 different geographic locations I've bumped into the 3 headed hellhound some of you already have.

Is there any way to get from a remote HPUX shell variable the following remote info:

- zoneinfo (Country/City)
- UTC + offset (I can easily get this from the zoneinfo)

So far the best I could get is the OS abbreviated timezone 
(is this enough to iteratively cross the remote time with a statically built pytz.common_timezones collection and reverse convert the abbreviated zones into Country/City or I'm completely going the wrong way?)

I can easily get the offset after getting the Country/City (which I haven't)

```
datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Dili')).strftime('%Z %z')
```

'TLT +0900'

- get remote abbreviated timezone,

(Linux has the far more sane

```
grep "ZONE=" /etc/sysconfig/clock
```

output like,
ZONE="Europe/London"
while HP-UX /etc/TIMEZONE uses abbreviated timezones like
TZ=CAT-2

I'd use echo $TZ which would output a little more useful data like CAT-2 but some remote HP-UXes don't even have this configured thus forcing me to rely on the ambiguous RFC822 date,

```
date +%z
```

CAT

I've looked both into pytz, datetime.datetime, email.Utils but considering it's a no can do directly converting from abbreviated time into the zoneinfo Country/City (pytz allows the opposite)
should I just scratch this Don Quixote quest of autodiscovering the remote timezone and
just add a Country/City dropdown list when accepting the user input registering the remote host?

**EDIT (Partial solution)**

**building on @Mike Pennington answer**

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta as td
from dateutil.relativedelta import *
from email.Utils import mktime_tz, parsedate_tz

hpux_remote_date = 'Thu Apr 28 18:09:20 TLT 2011'
utctimestamp = mktime_tz(parsedate_tz( hpux_remote_date ))  

hpux_dt = dt.fromtimestamp( utctimestamp )
delta_offset = relativedelta(dt.utcnow(), hpux_dt)

hpux_utc = hpux_dt + delta_offset

# Sanity checking to ensure we are correct...
hpux_dt
datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 28, 18, 9, 20)
hpux_utc
datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 28, 9, 9, 22, 229148)
```

Comment: what is it, exactly, that you are asking? Is this a user interface question? A question about how to extract timezones from timestamps? Or maybe how to determine the geographic location of a server?

Comment: "it's a no can do converting from abbreviated time into the zoneinfo Country/City" - this is also not quite possible. What would be '+0100'? Is it 'Europe/London' in summer or 'Europe/Berlin' or 'Europe/Paris' in winter?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, it's perfectly clear to me.  He is having problems deriving data from HPUX shell variables into something he can use as a `pytz` offset

Comment: @Mike Pennington: Ok, but the only actual question in his question is "Should I scratch this Don Quixote question... and just add a Country/City dropdown...?". I think the question could be more plainly stated.

Comment: Sorry guys, put too much info trying to frame my goal,
I'll edit it, summing it up,
I need a seamless way to use any remote info so I can get the local server vs remote ones Country/City and UTC offset.

Comment: @stack_zen, in your posted solution you have `delta_offset = relativedelta(dt.utcnow(), hpux_dt)`, but this ignores the addition of about 2 seconds.  Two notes, first you get a `timedelta` object automatically when you subtract two `datetimes`, so there shouldn't be a need for `relativedelta`... second, I would use the hack of dividing by integer 3600 and then multiplying by 3600 (see my answer) to ensure your delta offsets keep the original time as accurately as possible.

Comment: Right, 
using relativedelta here would be overkill, a subtraction between the datetime objects is enough in most cases, there are however some timezones using 5 min, 30 min or 45 min as their base unit, so one should use the roundup with caution.

By the way, those 2 extra seconds only were returned because I was running it in interactive shell :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to find your GMT offset like this...

### As a GMT offset, disregarding DST

`(time.localtime()[3] - time.localtime()[8]) - time.gmtime()[3]`

I am in Central time (GMT - 6) so, this yields `-6` on my system.

### As a GMT offset, including DST compensation

`(time.localtime()[3]) - time.gmtime()[3]`

This yields `-5` on my system.

It's probably easiest to go with the second option and use it to convert those local HPUX times into GMT; then mangle with `pytz` as-required.

### EDIT

If you are working with a text representation of remote (non-GMT) timestamps, it is probably easier to work directly with datetime objects... I don't have HPUX handy, but I'll assume the date string is similar to my debian squeeze system.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> from datetime import timedelta as td
>>> # using os.popen() to simulate the results of a HPUX shell 'date'...
>>> # substitute the real HPUX shell date string in hpux_date
>>> hpux_date = os.popen('date').read().strip()
>>> hpux_dt = dt.strptime(hpux_date, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
>>> # Rounding to the nearest hour because there *will* be slight delay
>>> # between shell string capture and python processing
>>> offset_seconds = ((dt.utcnow() - hpux_dt).seconds//3600)*3600
>>> hpux_gmt = hpux_dt + td(0,offset_seconds)
>>> # Sanity checking to ensure we are correct...
>>> hpux_gmt
datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 27, 17, 21, 58)
>>> hpux_dt
datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 27, 12, 21, 58)
>>> hpux_date
'Wed Apr 27 12:21:58 CDT 2011'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, 
you got my initial question at the first time.
I've upvoted the answer but could you please ellaborate?
(I have Python in my RHEL server, not in the HP-UX ones so I need to parse some datetime output and convert it locally to something like UTC)
Your example handles same day hourly differences but is timezone naive, what if the remote and local tz are in different days?
Don't I need all the times converted to UTC and localize them?

Comment: @stack_zen, please see my edit above... I think this should solve the problem.  This also accounts for systems with a different calendar date

Comment: hpux_dt = dt.strptime(hpux_date, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
works for local times but not for alien ones, considering %Z is platform-specific (only recognizes the time.tzname values, plus UTC and GMT).
Also, the offset computation is error prone to local/remote datetimes where the time is different.

thus I've lightly rewritten your suggestion (added an answer to preserve indentation) for extra sturdiness on the cost of extra imports

Comment: @stack_zen, thanks for letting me know... it's not hard to rewrite with a regex to parse out the required info, but hopefully this will get you where you need to go